# How to create a Custom control with controls inside of it so I can repeat it 25 times on webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need To create a form that has at least 25 of the fallowing rows. The user is going to add data and these would be saved to an existing data base with 6 Fields. What is the best way to do this. Can you create a Custom control which has this three controls inside of it ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
----------------   -----------  --------------
|               | |          |  |            |  
|  Text Box     | |   Label  |  | Text Box   |  
----------------  ------------  -------------
```

I created this ListView :

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource2" >
<LayoutTemplate>
<table cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" runat="server" id="tblProducts">
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
          <th id="Th1" runat="server">EmployeeID</th>
          <th id="Th2" runat="server">Name</th>
          <th id="Th3" runat="server">Absentee Code</th>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
</table>    
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<tr runat="server">
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>    
</ItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/EmptyRows.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<div style="height: 36px">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submitt" />
</div>
```

.VB code to try to get the values of each row but not working

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lview As ListViewItem

    For Each lview In ListView1.Items

        Dim control As Control = lview.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim resutltxtb1 = control.Text.ToString

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Repeater or ListView with the ItemTemplate of what you desire.  Bind to it 25 blank rows, and this will appear as you desire.  On save, you can loop through the rows to get the control values. using `FindControl()`.

Comment: I created the List View and it looks like I wanted to but I still don't know how to bind it to 25 empty rows. Do you mean Create a database with 3 fields and 25 empty rows? And bind it to that? Sorry I'm new on this.

Comment: Yes, create 25 empty records; doesn't have to be DB, can just simply be `list.DataSource = new ArrayList { new { First = "", Second = "", Third = "" }, new { First = "", Second = "", Third = "" }, .. }`

Comment: I Did it using XML and it worked! thank you @Brian Mains. I was trying to read the values of the text boxes using Dim lview as ListViewItem. For each lview IN ListView1.Items. But when I do lview.Subitem(1). Itn doesnt show the subItems? Any suggestions ?

Comment: To get a control from the item, you have to do `listViewitem.FindControl("Control ID")` and cast it to the correct control type.  Make sure you are on an item record (not header or footer) as that may not work.  To do that, check the ItemType property is of type 'Item'.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated my question and thats how im trying to get the values of each column but not working. I dont know if i misunderstood your answer. As shown on the code i get the control. But then if I try to get the value using control.Text it gives me an error. Text is not a memeber of System.Web.UI.Control. Cna you help me ?

Comment: You need an `If(lView.ItemType == <Item>) Then` wrapper around this, and you need to cast to a textbox, not string.  That error is correct: `Dim control As TextBox = CType(lview.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)`

Comment: Thanks It worked! Can I ask you a last question of topic a little bit. I need to be able to Write something on the label when Textbox1 leaving. I have been researching a lot. What is the best way to do this since is inside of the List View. Or is it Better to take a different route and use maybe User Control? Can you give me a hint please ? I don't want to have to create 25 Textbox, 25 Labels, 25 Textbox.